# How to make advanced TextBox?

Tags: c#, textbox, windows-forms-designer

How can I make autocomplete TextBox that suggests each word while typing? For example, if the input is `d`, suggestions should be `dog` and `dig`. when `dog` is selected and space/enter is pressed, user continues to type and types `j`. Then new suggestions should be `jump`, `jane`, `job` etc.
How can I implement that?

Comment: So you want a Autocomplete textbox?

Comment: [WinForms | C# | AutoComplete in the Middle of a Textbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437002/winforms-c-sharp-autocomplete-in-the-middle-of-a-textbox)

Comment: Follow this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control

Comment: What have you tried? Do you really need to implement this as it's sounds like an autocomplete box which, there are surely a number of existing implementations and third party scripts for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WindowsForms TextBox already has a auto complete feature:

```
    textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange(new string[] { "dog","dig", "jump","jane","job"});
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for detailed information.

Comment: This is the simplest way of implementing auto complete, but as far as I can see, it does not support multiple words...only the first.

Comment: It shows you a list of matching words in the dictionary if this is the support of multiple words you mean.

Comment: I copied your example into a unit test and typed; "dog". Sure enough, it showed up an auto complete list for all words beginning with "d", but then I tried to type "j" after "dog", and no auto complete list showed up.

Comment: As long as there is no word starting with "dj" in your autocomplete list for sure nothing will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

The following link shows a great example of this . . .  http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/737799/IntelliSense-TextBox-in-Csharp