# Change the auto-complete behaviour of a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox, selection

I have two doubts about the autocomplete feature of textboxes in C#.

First, I want to display the full list, not only the ones that start with the given text, and secondly I want to prevent the auto-complete of specific options (some are category titles).

I've been checking the textbox properties and there's nothing related to it, so probably the main question could be, Is there a way to modify / override the textbox events in order to handle the auto-complete actions? (I don't know if it applies to show the full list too)

Comment: Winform, Wpf, Asp.net...?

Comment: Windows Forms, thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking about a winforms textbox, as I dont think the WPF textbox supports autocomplete at all.

The base `TextBox` class will not support doing what you want, so you could in theory attempt to override all of the functionality in the `TextBox` class to do what you want, but the better idea would be to create a new custom control that inherits from `TextBoxBase` and implement the autocomplete behavior the way you want it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about displaying the full list (perhaps a combobox or similar is more suited to this?) but you can definitely do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control) to swap which list of possible items can be displayed.

Another option, though one I like less, is to remove items you don't want to display at a given time from the collection dynamically, like this: `textBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Remove("ACategoryTitle")`

I could foresee that approach having many problems with trying to rebuild the list constantly.  I would probably create a subclass of `AutoCompleteStringCollection` that wraps some LINQ code to nicely select the union of some lists and not others to display in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to build my own autocomplete tool with the help of a simple listbox and events, then I could achieve what I was expecting..

The CodingGorilla's answer probably leads to a better solution if you want something more decent, in my case for speed reasons I decided to do it that way but I'll mark his answer as the accepted in order to help other people who have the same doubt and they could consider that point..