# Autocomplete property is not coming in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, pushdown-automaton

i am creating windows application's for PDA Windows CE.

i have a requirement to create text box with auto-complete option , it seems auto-complete property available in VS 2005 , but in VS 2008 this property is does not exist.

because PDA applications can be created only in visual studio 2008 , other higher versions are not supporting.

FYI,Property Image,
[image]
any advise regarding above?

Comment: Please check this link  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletemode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @vikassinghaswal in Visual Studio 2008 , i cannot see auto-complete property.

Comment: you can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control)

Comment: @UmarAli , AutoCompleteMode property is not coming in visual studio 2008.is there any way to enable this particular property ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to check the Visual Studio settings for Statement Completion, found in:

Tools | Options | Text Editor | All Languages | General | Statement completion

Make sure that the "Auto list members" and "Parameter information" text boxes are checked.  If the control assemblies are installed correctly, the members should show up in Intellisense properly.

Comment: i have checked the above path , as u said Auto list members and Parameter Information check boxes was in checked mode. what will be the other problems ? why VS 2008 is not having autocomplete property ?