# Search Suggestions API and AutoComplete TextBox in

Tags: c#

I have a class returns a list of *Google Suggestions* based on a text that passed to it. My question is:

> How can I use this class to work as an AutoCompleteCustomSource for a textbox tool so user can write text in it and that text sent to this class to bring a list of Suggestions as user is writing and every litter that user add will be added to the text which will be sent again to the class to bring more Suggestions?

For example, this call to that class fills `textbox1` with list of Suggestions based on "***arduino***" word:

```
SearchSuggestionsAPI search = new SearchSuggestionsAPI();
IList result = (await search.GetSearchSuggestions("arduino"));
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    string sent = result[i].ToString();
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(result[i].ToString());
    textBox1.AppendText(sent);
    textBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoComplete TextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but something like this may work:

```
private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var results = (await search.GetSearchSuggestions(textBox1.Text));

    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear();
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource.AddRange( results );
}
```

Comment: I tried your code and I have an error as 'result' needs to be declared and if I add:
SearchSuggestionsAPI search = new SearchSuggestionsAPI();
I have error in the last code line as 'results' can't be converted to string[]

Comment: the error I'm having is because my class returns a list not an array

Comment: @khalefa you should be able to cast it with something like this: `Array array = results.Cast<string>().ToArray();`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried it and I got this error: 
Unable to cast object of type 'ConsoleApplication1.GoogleSuggestion' to type 'System.String

Comment: @khalefa I thought that your `GetSearchSuggestions` was returning a list of `String`. If your object implements a `ToString()` method, you can do `var array = results.Select(s => s.ToString()).ToArray()`. You need an array of strings to use in the AutoCompleteCustomSource...