# How to make a textbox automatically catch what the user is typing?

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm creating a login form, and like what the title says, is there a way to make my textbox (textbox for the username in this case) catch whatever the user is typing? I want to copy what the Facebook homepage does. If you're not logged in, and you go to FB, and try typing in, whatever it is that you typed, it appears to the textbox labeled "Email or Phone." Also, I'm new to C#.

Edit: I want the textbox to catch the text that the user typed in, even if the user did not select the said textbox. I'm not really good in English so I don't know how to properly phrase what I want to say. Sorry.

Edit 2 (from my comment below): I want to apologize again for my English. I'm gonna try again. For example, I opened the login form, and then it appeared. No control is selected or is in focus. Now, when the user type something, I want the textbox for the user to be in focus, and whatever was typed by the user be also typed there.

Comment: So you are talking not only about catching but about storing what has been written into the textBox right? That *some* textBoxes can get autofilled in on the next launch?

Comment: I think what you want is AutoComplete. You could read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control

Comment: There is not control that saves the data typed or entered before on it's own. You will have to save all the Usernames that have been logged-in and based on that you can either create a custom textbox that fills itself or use  a third party control.

Comment: I think I used the wrong term, so I edited my post. I'm not talking about AutoComplete.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL I still don't understand you completely. So you want to store what the user wrote in the textBox and then?

Comment: That's just it. So, that when the login form appears, and the user types, whatever he/she wrote will be stored in the username textbox.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Please have a look at my answer, does this fit your needs? Furthermore, what do you mean by this: `I want the textbox to catch the text that the user typed in, even if the user did not select the said textbox.` ?

Comment: I want to apologize again for my English. I'm gonna try again. For example, I opened the login form, and then it appeared. No control is selected or is in focus. Now, when the user types something, I want the _txt_username_ to be in focus, and whatever was typed by the user be also typed there. Do you get me now? I'm really sorry.

Comment: I'm gonna try making a video of it. Lol.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Please have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that's basically the intention of a event. You should use the `TextChanged()` event of your `TextBox`. This event will be invoked each time the content of the property `textBox1.Text` changes.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    targetTextBox.Text = textBox1.Text;
}
```

You could store the text value as well in a `string` property for further global use. Instead of a plain `string` property, you could use a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` as well. As *key* you could store the specific user logged in as a `string` and it's *value* could be a `List<string>` of all the inputs this specific user has written.

---

**Edit according to the new needs of OP:**

So at first you should set the focus to your desired `textBox`. If I understand you right, you want this to happen right after the login form loaded. So add this to the end of your constructor of the login form.

```
this.ActiveControl = textBox1; /* name of the textBox you want to set focus to*/
```

Then subscribe to the `TextChanged` event for the `textBox` that gets the focus and that's it. That could be done the easiest way in the `properties` window that shows once you look at the design of your form.

---

**Edit according to the new provided code:** This is about setting the focus to `textBox1` referring to the code environment of OP.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Hide();

    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();

    Show();

    //simply setting the focus here
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}
```

Or you could e.g. subscribe to the event `Form1_VisibleChanged()`. Then you don't even need to set the focus in the constructor, just in this event.

```
private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}
```

This event gets every time fired when the visibility of `Form1` gets changed, so even on the first initialisation or after every invoke of `Show()`.

Comment: I'll try this but to be honest, I don't think I get it. But thanks anyway! I will update you if it does what I want.

Comment: Then tell me what you don't understand and please describe your needs again.

Comment: Okay, so I already did this earlier. It worked but I was also using an errorprovider which I got from a tutorial I was watching earler. If there are no errors, and I click the login button, form b will open. When you close form b, the login form appears again. I already have the *this.ActiveControl = txt_username* set when the login form is activated. So, *txt_username* should be in focus when the login form appears again, right? But the next textbox which is for the password is the one getting the focus. Hope you get me.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL I guess this has something to do with how you show the login form the second time. I guess that you don't completely recreate the whole form and that could be why the `ActiveControl` doesn't get set again. You should post the code how to close/hide/whatever the login form when you open form b. And how you show the login form the second time when form b gets closed.

Comment: I just hide the login form when I show form b. I'm guessing it doesn't get recreated when I show it again because I'm just unhiding it. Even so, I put the 'ActiveControl' in the Activated event which means that when I show the login form after closing form b, the login form is getting the focus which I think then activates the Activated event. Am I wrong? Edit: Okay, so even I was confused with my English lol

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Please post the code of the hiding and showing of the login form. Furthermore I have never heard of an `Activated` event of a form, you might post that code as well, but the important part is the hide/show action. Because according to how you did it, we have to adjust how and when we set the `ActiveControl` to the textBox. *By the way you can delete the code of the hide/show part in the question later on again*.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Is the `mainForm` form b from the above example?

Comment: I can't get through your code, even since there are quite a few other methods. But let's get it simple. So you use `FormB.Showdialog` and for the login form you show it again with `this.Show()` right?

Comment: Yeah, form b is 'mainForm'. I do it like [this](https://imgur.com/a/31ZWN). I commented out those two lines because sometimes I don't want the first form to hide. Btw, why can't I @ you?

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Ok, so normally those two lines are not commented and then login form (Form1) gets shown then with `Show()`? You can't @ me here, I guess because this is my answer and I already get a notification for every comment under my answer. :-)

Comment: When they're not commented out, the login form (form 1) hides, then mainForm (form 2) appears. Then, when I close form 2, form 1 shows up automatically. I don't even know how did that work like that. Lol. I just used to instantiate a new form 1 on the `closing` event of form 2 before I found this method. So, there were always lots of hidden form 1 in the background when I switch back and forth between the two forms. Lol.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Ok, but now  you work with `Hide()` and `Show()`. I will write some test code and then tell you my results. But just to understand you right, the issue here is that you want to focus the textBox after form 1 gets shown again, right?

Comment: Yeah. Btw, this issue only occurs when I use and press the key that I set in the `AcceptButton`. When I'm just clicking the login button, the `txt_username` gets the focus after closing the form 2.

Comment: @G40-ovoneL Yes the issue was that the `Activated` event is not meant for that. I updated my answer with two different solutions. I tested both and they work fine. I prefer the second solution, since the code is cleaner. Due to my effort I would appreciate if you upvote and accept my answer, since everything works fine now. :-)

Comment: Thank you!!! It's working now. I already upvoted you yesterday but it doesn't change your score publicly since reputation score is low :/

Comment: I just wanna add that the `click` event is what worked for me. Thanks again!

Comment: I've just learned now that you can accept an answer. I already marked your answer accepted. Apologies, and thank you again!

Comment: @G40-ovoneL You are welcome man. I am glad I could help you out.