# Textbox string matching

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a suggestion in a textbox based on the input. I am trying to input a number (50 for example) and make the textbox suggest what I am trying to type. I have the following data contained in **vars.str** variable:

```
AU-60-ST-F
AU-60-CA-F
AU-61-ST-F
```

Here is the code that I am using

```
private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AutoCompleteStringCollection col2 = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    //

    for (int i = 0; i < vars.str.Count; i++)
    {
        if(vars.str[i].IndexOf(textBox2.Text) != -1)
        {
            label1.Text = "TRUE";
            string match = Regex.Replace(vars.str[i], @"-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[MF]", "");
            col2.Add(match);
        }
    }
    textBox2.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col2;
}
```

The suggestion should be AU-60 if I put 60 in the textbox, AU-61 if I put 61 in the textbox

The code seems to work - my testing label changes to TRUE but I do not get any suggestions below the textbox. Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Auto complete textBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control)

Comment: Did you set `textBox2.AutoCompleteMode`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoComplete TextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control)

Comment: @zdimension, yes, it is set to textBox2.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;

Comment: You have to make it suggestAppend @J Doe and the source is CustomSource

Comment: @Kaj it is set to customsource and suggestappend does not work - still nothing