# Textbox Auto-complete C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox with concatenated values of (*First Name* + **space** + *Last Name*) from database. When I type 'M' it suggests names that start with **M** but when I type surname value (ex. 'Enrique') it doesn't suggest names with surname 'Enrique'. Anyone could help me ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoComplete TextBox Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control)

Comment: Please paste the code

Comment: [AutoComplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796195/c-sharp-autocomplete)