# Search box for application settings

Tags: c#

How would one reproduce the functionality of the settings search (ctrl + Q) in Visual Studio 2017?

I have a desktop application that launches a tabbed form that holds all settings for the app.

Currently, if a user wants to find a setting, they must click a tab, then navigate to that setting.

I'd like to create a search box at the top of the form that would allow the user to type in a keyword for a particular setting. Below the search box, a list would populate so the user could see all the settings with that particular keyword as shown in this picture.
[Visual Studio settings search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py16E.png)

Has anyone here reproduced this? If so, how did you do it? If not, how would you do it?

Comment: You could do something like loop through all labels in your tab groups and look for the names there.  Then you could determine which tab page it was on and make that one visible upon clicking the search result.

Answer (score 0):

On your place I would look into suggestion on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357853/autocomplete-textbox-control) first.

Usign [AutocompleteSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletesource?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [AutoCompleteMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode?view=netframework-4.7.2) could be definitelly helpful for you. I don't know, but you would probasbly need to change a format of your data, i.e. from configuration to some kind of list.